# Sending knockout viewmodel to controller is missing items from drop down box

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout-mvc

Little by little I'm learning this...

In my C#/MVC4 demo build I've created a controller to send data to my view through JSON.  In my view I am able to parse the response and populate a drop down list.

I'm using knockout similar to a cart to create additional lines (colors) for posting to the controller.

code:

MVC ViewModel:

```
function Color(data) {
    this.ID = ko.observable(data.ID);
    this.ColorName = ko.observable(data.ColorName);
    this.Duration = ko.observable(data.Duration);
    this.bNotPermanent = ko.observable(1);
}

function ViewModel() {
    self = this;
    self.CurrentColors = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.AddColors = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.AllColors = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetUsersColors", "EditUser")',
        data: { szUserRecID: RecID },
        success: function (data) {
            var colors = $.map(data, function (item) {
                return new Color(item)
            });
            self.CurrentColors(colors);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.status + " : " + err.statusText);
        }
    })

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetVisibleColors", "EditColor")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json", 
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            var colors = $.map(data, function (item) {
                return new Color(item)
            });
            self.AllColors(colors);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.status + " - " + err.statusText);
        }
    })

    self.removeLine = function (color) { self.AddColors.remove(color);

    };
    self.addColor = function (color) { 
        self.AddColors.push(new Color({ ColorName: "", ID: "", Duration: "Permanent" }))
    };

    self.save = function () 
    {
        // I've also tried data: ko.mapping.toJSON(this) 
        // based on my issues I've seen, I'm almost positive this is where my issue is
        // I think the mapping is having an issue but I don't know what it should look like
        // with an array of objects
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("PostColors", "EditColor")',
            type: "POST",
            data: ko.mapping.toJSON(this.AddColors()),
            async: true,
            contentType: "application/json"
        }).success(function (data) {

        });

};
```

this does work...

View

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr data-bind =" visible: $root.AddColors().length > 0">
        <th padding: 10px; >Color</th>
        <!--<th padding: 10px; >Duration</th>-->
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: AddColors">
    <tr>
    <!-- This works, it displays all the colors provided by the controller -->
        <td><select data-bind="options: $root.AllColors, optionsText: 'ColorName', value: ID, optionsCaption: 'Select Color...'"></select></td>
        <td>
            <a href='#' data-bind='click: $parent.removeLine'>Remove</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<button data-bind='click: addColor'>Add Color</button>


<button data-bind='click: save'>Submit Colors</button>
```

controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void PostColors(List<ViewModels.ColorList> AddColors)
    {

           int t = 0; // to set a break point only
    }
```

C# ViewModel

```
    public class ColorList
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string ColorName { get; set; }
    public string Duration{ get; set; }
    public bool bNotPermanent { get; set; }
}
```

when I inspect AddColors in the above function, the Duration is set but the ColorName is null but I do have the correct number of elements coming through.

I can add lines(colors) over and over on the form and selecting them on the list.  But why are they not showing in "AddColors" object list?

I did find another article on here referring to get; set; in the viewmodel and I did add that.  Up until that point everything coming through was null.

Fiddler is showing this (and it doesn't look quite right...?)

```
[{"ID":    {"ID":11,"ColorName":"Green","Duration":null,"bNotPermanent":1},"ColorName":"","Duration":"Permanent","bNotPermanent":1},{"ID":    {"ID":17,"ColorName":"Red","Duration":null,"bNotPermanent":1},"ColorName":"","Duration":"Permanent","bNotPermanent":1}]
```

I really think my issue is with the data conversion / ajax post.  Question is, what should it look like?

Comment: Can your post your `ViewModels.ColorList`? Otherwise it seems you are missing `optionsValue: 'ID'` from your `select` but it is hard to tell what do you want to achieve with this `addColor` method... If you are creating new colors why do you want to select from an already existing one? Or do you want to create a color list from the already created colors?

Comment: I added the viewmodel to the bottom of the question above.  For the post, the ID is not mandatory.... (they don't exist in the DB yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want the ID of the color to appear in the `ID` field on the added color entry. If so, what you need to do is that you need to set the `optionsValue` binding to select a single property from the selected item and use the value of that property to set the property you are binding to.

The [Knockout documentation on the options binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) states the following regarding the `optionsValue` binding.

> Similar to optionsText, you can also pass an additional parameter called optionsValue to specify which of the objects’ properties should be used to set the value attribute on the  elements that KO generates.

Since you don't want the whole object to be set into the `ID` property of your added color, you want Knockout to pick the `ID` property from the color. So just update your binding from:

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.AllColors, 
                   optionsText: 'ColorName', 
                   value: ID, 
                   optionsCaption: 'Select Color...'">
</select>
```

to:

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.AllColors, 
                   optionsText: 'ColorName', 
                   optionsValue: ID,
                   value: ID, 
                   optionsCaption: 'Select Color...'">
</select>
```

Comment: I have, by the way, set up a jsfiddle mostly using your bindings and viewmodel (some alterations, like the one mentioned above, removing the colorName from the posted-data (since the color ID should be more important than the color name) and removing usages of AJAX). It also continously shows what the JSON structure looks like, as you change stuff. You can find it, and toy with it, at http://jsfiddle.net/6Wtf8/

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response, I got pulled into another project unexpectedly and now I'm back at this.  I added in the options value and reset the breakpoint in the controller at this line (as above) int t = 0; // to set a break point only  

The AddColors variable is still blank/null...

Comment: I just noticed that it appears that they do come through on Request.Form.  Is that the right place to pull this data from or should I work on getting the data through the viewModel?

Comment: However, I'm not sure the data is correct....  This is what fiddler has for it: 
[{"ID":{"ID":12,"ColorName":"Red","Duration":null,"bNotPermanent":1},"ColorName":"","Duration":"Permanent","bNotPermanent":1},{"ID":{"ID":17,"ColorName":"Green","Duration":null,"bNotPermanent":1},"ColorName":"","Duration":"Permanent","bNotPermanent":1}]

Comment: No, that data does not look correct. Have you looked at the jsfiddle I linked to above? That jsfiddle does not create data in the format you seem to get from something. Have a look at the jsfiddle and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Nevermind... I as thinking fiddler.  That is a cool tool!  The issue seemed to be with how I was building the new object on:

self.addColor = function (color) { 
        self.AddColors.push(new Color({ ID: "", Duration: "Permanent" }))

Your version works and the data look like it should be in the correct format.  However my controller (PostColors(List<ViewModels.ColorList> AddColors)) still doesn't see the view. Do I need to get the data from the form or the view?

Comment: viewmodel is the wrong term to use...  To clarify, the controller function: public JsonResult PostGroups(List<ViewModels.ColorList> AddColors) has the "AddColors" null when the function is hit so the data is not getting sent into the controller.  I can see the objects on the Request.Form but I don't seem to be able to access them that way either using GetValues....